# wiring up GuiceServletContextListener to an existing injector

Tags: java, jersey, jetty, guice, swagger

I have a large existing java program already using Guice.  I'm trying to add an embedded website with swagger documentation.  Somehow I need to wire it all up with Guice, but everything I've tried throws null pointer exception when I try to use things I injected in my main program.  I thought maybe I could pass the injector and wire it up that way, either using the injector or creating a child injector.

I've created a sample app using just the code needed to get this working, with a URL that works but doesn't try to grab use the injections from my main program, and one that does not work that tries to use the injection.

I'm trying to do all this without needing the web.xml via:

```
    private ContextHandler buildApiContext() {

    ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig();
    // Replace EntityBrowser with your resource class
    // io.swagger.jaxrs.listing loads up Swagger resources
    resourceConfig.packages("web", ApiListingResource.class.getPackage().getName());

    //apiServletContainer.reload(resourceConfig);
    ServletContainer apiServletContainer = new ServletContainer(resourceConfig);

    final ServletContextHandler apiContext = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    apiContext.setContextPath("/api");      
    ServletHolder apiBrowser = new ServletHolder(apiServletContainer);
    apiContext.addFilter(GuiceFilter.class, "/*", EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));
    myGuiceServletContextListener.setMainInjector(blackboard.getMainInjector());
    apiContext.addEventListener(myGuiceServletContextListener);
    apiContext.addServlet(apiBrowser, "/*");        
    return apiContext;
}
```

and

```
public class MyGuiceServletContextListener extends GuiceServletContextListener {

    @Inject private Blackboard blackboard;  
    @Override
    protected Injector getInjector() {
        return blackboard.getMainInjector();
    }}
```

I also tried:

```
return blackboard.getMainInjector().createChildInjector();
```

In my main I'm starting the main program injection with:

```
Config config = ReadConfig.createConfig();
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new Bindings(config));
BigProgramInterface bbInterface = injector.getInstance(BigProgramImpl.class);
bbInterface.start(injector);
```

where Bindings looks like

```
public class Bindings implements Module {

private Config config;

public Bindings(Config config) {
    this.config = config;
}

public void configure(Binder binder) {

    Integer fixedThreadPoolSize = 2;
    Executor fixedExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(fixedThreadPoolSize, new FixedThreadFactory());
    binder.bind(Executor.class).toInstance(fixedExecutor);

    binder.bind(Config.class).toInstance(config);
    binder.bind(Blackboard.class).asEagerSingleton();
    binder.bind(BigProgramMain.class).asEagerSingleton();
    binder.bind(EmbeddedWeb.class).asEagerSingleton();
    //binder.bind(MyGuiceServletContextListener.class).asEagerSingleton();
}
```

The blackboard is injected, and it is getting the main injector, but it can't *use* it.

works:

```
@Path("/test")
@Api (value = "/test")
public class TestSwagger {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestSwagger.class);
@GET
@Path("/get")
@ApiOperation(value = "a working test", 
    notes = "Returns my test class", 
    response = MyTest.class, 
    responseContainer="Class")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getResult() {
    MyTest myTest = new MyTest();
    myTest.setMyTestString("this is a test");
    return Response.ok().entity(myTest).build();    
}}
```

not working:

```
@Path("/testbad")
@Api (value = "/testbad")
public class TestSwaggerBad {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestSwaggerBad.class);
@Inject private Blackboard blackboard;
@GET
@Path("/get")
@ApiOperation(value = "a non - working test", 
    notes = "Returns my test class", 
    response = MyTest.class, 
    responseContainer="Class")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getResult() {
    MyTest myTest = new MyTest();
    myTest.setMyTestString(blackboard.getBigProgramCounter().toString());
    return Response.ok().entity(myTest).build();    
}}
```

Please see my code for the nitty gritty details:
https://github.com/phomlish/SwaggerSampleApiWebsite

Comment: Your issue is that your resource class (TestSwaggerBad) is not guice managed. How would guice know to inject a field in there if you don't create the instance of the Swagger code in guice itself? If you wanted that to work, you will need to bridge jersey injection to guice injection. Guice comes with jersey integration out of the box, so you could also take advantage of that

Comment: I'm still not clear on how to do either.  Please confirm that a deeper understanding and attempt to implement HK2 Guice bridging is the right path to proceed.

Comment: Another comment: I had a bit of a look into how DW guicey solves that issue, and the "out-of-box" integration I mentioned in fact does exactly what I outline in the answer manually. Sorry about that. I hope I could help. By the way you might want to consider a framework like Dropwizard that makes all of this much easier for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a closer look at your code, here is how you get it to work:

Add the guice bridge to your pom:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.hk2/guice-bridge -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
    <artifactId>guice-bridge</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0-b15</version>
</dependency>
```

That adds the guice hk2 bridge to your configuration. Now, you will want to wire that up. For that, we will create a feature as outlined by this post:

[Guice don't inject to Jersey's resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35085267/guice-dont-inject-to-jerseys-resources)

```
@Priority(0)
public class GuiceFeature implements Feature {

    private Injector i;

    public GuiceFeature(Injector i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean configure(FeatureContext context) {
        ServiceLocator locator = ServiceLocatorProvider.getServiceLocator(context);

        GuiceBridge.getGuiceBridge().initializeGuiceBridge(locator);
        GuiceIntoHK2Bridge guiceBridge = locator.getService(GuiceIntoHK2Bridge.class);
        guiceBridge.bridgeGuiceInjector(i);

        return true;
    }

}
```

Note that I am passing the injector that you created into that feature. This is important since you will need that same injector in order to be able to find your service. The binding code is fairly straight forward.

Finally, you will need to register that feature. In your class EmbeddedWeb, you add:

EmbeddedWeb#buildApiContext:

```
resourceConfig.register(new GuiceFeature(myGuiceServletContextListener.getInjector()));
```

Again, we are using the same injector that you created already.

Finally that is all that you need and your services are wired up correctly.

test:

```
artur@pandaadb:~/dev/repo/SwaggerSampleApiWebsite$ curl "http://localhost:8080/api/testbad/get"
{"myTestString":"10"}
```

Hope that helps,

artur

EDIT '''IMPORTANT''':

For injection, you can not use guice annotations. Jersey doesn't seem to recognise them (likely because they did not want to add guice dependencies). Luckily, guice can work with both javax and guice annotations. So in your TestSwaggerBad class you will also need to change the import to standard javax annotations.

Comment: Random note: i actually checked out and built your project. I can commit my code, however you would have to grand me temporary access to your example

Comment: I sent you an invite to be a collaborator, will that suffice?  The changes you have outlined are quite significant.  Google failed me when I tried to figure all this out.  Thanks so much for taking a look and the hard work, I'm hoping others will stumble upon my question and your contribution and will be able to learn from the work that has gone into this!

Comment: @phomlish hi - thank you, i pushed my changes to your repo

Comment: Thank you @pandaadb!  That worked (although I did have to remove the Override in GuiceFeature to get rid of a compile error).  Looks like your previous post pointing me to hk2 would have gotten me to the solution eventually, but you did it all for me.  I sincerely appreciate your help in fixing my injections.  I'll fix up the documentation and push it up so others might benefit.

Comment: @phomlish sounds good :) If your issue is fixed, you can accept the answer as correct :)