# Working of Google's Guice with Dropwizard

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, dropwizard

I went through the [official documentation](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Motivation) of Guice and It says that We need to create an injector with all the Guice Modules and then call something like:

```
  Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new BillingModule());
    BillingService billingService = injector.getInstance(BillingService.class);
```

But when I am going through the [dropwizard-guice](https://github.com/HubSpot/dropwizard-guice) [example](https://github.com/eliast/dropwizard-guice-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/helloworld/HelloWorldApplication.java). It is creating GuiceBundle and adding It to **bootstrap**:

```
bootstrap.addBundle(guiceBundle);
```

I want to understand It's internal working that how it is linking **@Inject** written anywhere in the code with the instances provides by Guice bundles.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 4):

Dropwizard is bundled with Jersey which comes with its own HK2 DI.

If you try to use Guice injection as mentioned in your answer, Guice will have it's own context of modules which will not be available to HK2 modules.

For the above to work, one will need a library which will create a bridge among them. The *HubSpot/dropwizard-guice* is one such bridge library. This has to be done in the bootstrap phase of the application, so that when the Jersey is initialized, HK2 is aware about the Guice modules.

One can refer the following links for further information:

https://javaee.github.io/hk2/guice-bridge.html

[Guice don't inject to Jersey's resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35085267/guice-dont-inject-to-jerseys-resources)

Comment: Could you please share more insight of dropwizard-guice internal working with HK2

Comment: @niraj I've updated my answer to include links which will help understand the hk2 guice bridge and also how to implement one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell HubSpot's GuiceBundle where to look for resource classes.
 I guess, before Guice you had to tell same thing to Jersey.
Here's piece of code I use to init GuiceBundle
(assuming that all my resource classes live in the same package):

```
GuiceBundle<MyConfiguration> guiceBundle =
        GuiceBundle.<MyConfiguration>newBuilder()
                .addModule(new MyModule())
                .enableAutoConfig(MyResource.class.getPackage().getName())
                .setConfigClass(MyConfiguration.class)
                .build();
```

Comment: So, If I use @Inject in some class and I am creating an instance of that. Where that GuiceBundle is coming into the picture and how am I receiving an injected instance?

Comment: GuiceBundle comes from HubSpot's [dropwizard-guice](https://github.com/HubSpot/dropwizard-guice) mentioned above.  
Once you have constructors, setters or fields annotated with @Inject for resources, services and any other classes of your object tree, Guice should be able to do it's work.  
Please take a look at readme of dropwizard-guice (link above) for more details.